# Como descobrir a url base do Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Eu me lembro que, quando eu usava o framework Codeigniter, eu poderia descobri qual era a url base da aplicação, simplesmente chamando `base_url()`. No Laravel 3, eu usava `URL::base()`.

Porém agora, no Laravel 5, quando eu chamado `URL::base()`, retorna o seguinte erro:

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Method base does not exist.'

Testei no Laravel 4, e ocorre o mesmo erro.

Sendo assim, qual é a forma correta de descobrir a url base da aplicação, usando Laravel 4 ou 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem vários *helpers* para gerar [*urls* no Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#urls), é preciso entender qual seria o caso de uso onde você precisa só a *url* base.

Em todo caso, podemos usar o helper `url()` que existe [desde a versão 4](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.0/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L911) do Laravel.

```
$siteRoot = url('/');
```

É importante inserir o barra, pois a [partir do Laravel 5.2](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/e970dacf4ce0c72e5), o helper *url()* irá retornar uma [instância de *UrlGenerator*](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L797).

Comment: Informação importante. Quando você passa `NULL` em `url`, ele realmente retorna `UrlGenerator`. Não vi ainda, mas vou confirmar se ele  usa `__toString` internamente.

Comment: Usa não @WallaceMaxters

Comment: Eu vi aqui. É importante passar pelo menos uma `string` vazia. Interalmente ele verifica se o parâmetro é `NULL`.

Comment: Que o autor da resposta anterior não me leve a mal, mas eu creio que essa resposta está mais completa.

Answer (score 1):

Para saber o url base basta:

```
$base_url = url('/');
```

[Url helpers de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url)

Comment: Boa. Testei aqui no `php artisan tinker` (Laravel 4) e funcionou. Porém nem precisou chamar a barra, bastou apenas usar `url()`.

Answer (score 0):

Na versão 4 do Laravel, é possível fazer isso utilizando o método `URL::to()`, porém é necessário colocar uma barra ou uma string vazia como parâmetro.

```
 $base = URL::to('');

 // ou 

 $base = URL::to('/')
```

Isso também funcionará na versão 5 do Laravel, mas nesse caso é melhor usar a função `url()`, como mencionado na outra resposta.

Comment: Por que não utilizar o helper no Laravel 4? Ele já existia lá https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls

Comment: @gmsantos eu só descobri que tinha essa função agora que fiz a pergunta, hehehe. Em todo caso, eu costumo muito tentar manter um padrão. Percebi que a utilização de funções se tornou muito comum a partir do Laravel 5. Nas versões 4, era comum sempre ter uma classe Facade com um Alias, para você usar um recurso ou uma biblioteca de terceiro. De qualquer forma, essa informação é bem-vinda

Comment: Na época do Laravel 4 era mais comum mesmo as Facades, ainda bem que elas estão caindo em desuso

Comment: Também acho que facades as vezes podem gerar problemas, principalmente com o não uso de namespace (por padrão), pode gerar conflitos de nomes. Aí já viu, né.